# Not able to pull Private Images from Artifactory to AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am having an issue pulling private images from Artifactory to AWS Fargate. It is showing an error "access violation". Anybody getting the same error while running task in AWS Fargate?

Status reason : CannotPullContainerError: API error (500): Get https://xxx.artifactory.xx:xxx/v2/: Access violation

Comment: I get the EXACT same error with all the necessary stuff described here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/private-auth.html confirmed as implemented. Did you get a solution yet?

Comment: @MartinBartlett no. I think AWS Fargate can't authenticate the private docker registry that we use. It works from ECR but while using third party registry, it won't recognize.

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been fixed in Fargate Platform Version‐1.3.0.

In 1.3.0, along with Secrets support, AWS fixed the issue of pulling images from the private registry which runs on HTTPS ports other than 443.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/platform_versions.html

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/aws-fargate-platform-version-1-3-adds-secrets-support/

Answer (score 1):

AWS have recognized this as an issue with Fargate:

> Thank you for your patience. Here's an update which I received from our Fargate team on this issue.
>
> We have identified an issue were customers are unable to pull images from private container image registries running on non-443 HTTPS ports. We have fixed the issue and will make it available with the next AWS Fargate Platform Version release (mid December).
>
> I hope the above answers your questions and I do apologize for the issues you faced. Please do get back on the case if you needed more information. Have a great day ahead :)

To retry, then, after mid-December